# How to recreate this scary sound?

Tags: sound-design, horror

I love this scary sound from a game-series called Slendrina. How can I recreate it?
Thanks in advance.

The sound is called Slendrina Appearance 3 and here is the link (Warning: It's loud):

Comment: What equipment do you have to work with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: For your first question: I have so far designed my sound effects by recording some sound with real life objects with my phone and then edited them in Audacity, and I have also used Fl Studio and different plug ins to create some sounds.

Comment: For your second question: I don't have that much experience in sound design so that is why Im asking for help but I think there are 2 different sounds in this sound effect. One of those sounds like a hit with alot of reverb, so I can recreate that one pretty easily but there is also some other sound layered in the sound effect and I have no idea what that is or how to recreate it. So I would really appreciate some help with that. :)

Comment: It sounds like several layers of various hits, scrapes and bowing on a waterphone (https://youtu.be/foSJstDFDfg) - A staple of horror sound design!